# Counting rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering how I could count the number of rows in a MySql database using vb.net (as an integer)
It's quite a simple question as I am quite nooby with MySql and vb.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOURTABLENAME
```

In VB.NET you can try like this:

```
Private Sub btn_login_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click

        Dim con As New MySqlConnection(cnString)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOURTABLENAME ", con)
        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        cmd = Nothing
        con.Close()
        txt_count.Text = i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME